# How to stop wp-editor() overwriting my HTML?

Tags: wp-editor

I have the old problem that the WordPress editor overwrites my HTML code. For example, the editor inserts `<p>` and `<br>` tags where you don't have them set.

The second problem is the editor doesn't show the real source code. If I write some code in the editor, and update, and look afterwards at the source code in the front-end (e.g. with Firefox), it shows there are tags which I can't see in the back-end editor.

To suppress the problem, I installed the TinyMCE A. Editor, but it doesn't always work. Why must I have an external editor to change it? Can't WordPress have it's own solution for this little bug?

I wish that WordPress would have the option to switch the Editor ON or OFF, so the user can choose. Some kind of solution might be a supplement in `functions.php`, where you can add shortcodes; I think that is laborious, but could it be the real solution?

Comment: Have you looked at this plugin?: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-visual-editor-wysiwyg/

Comment: Thank you for answer.. but thats not my solution, I need the function visual editor too.. Only no overwrite!? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were always writing in HTML, you could add the following to your `functions.php` file:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

I do this for some of my own sites.

As it sounds like you want the option to turn this on or off, you may want to try the  [wpautop control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpautop-control/) plugin.

This should let you turn it off on your posts, while leaving it on for other users.

Comment: Hello, thanks your answer..
I always write in HTML, but the EndUser of my themes will have the visual edit.
I´ve heard that 
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); and the remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' ); will remove all empty -p- , -/p- elements from all over the document. so I don't want to try it out..I don't want to broke my complete work. Have you some experience with the filters? Run your editor so as you like, or will you become problems after switching between visual and html?

Comment: I've found a reference page, which have the solution with JQuery.. But I think, that WordPress provide itself, JQuery can´t be the solution, not all people like Javascript on her site and switch the browserfunction off. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710524/stop-wordpress-automatically-showing-p-p-tags

Comment: My end solution of the problem was now the description in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710524/stop-wordpress-automatically-showing-p-p-tags, with the supplement of the function.php from user ravi patel:

Comment: [raw][/raw] this way is the only way it runs so I want - hope this WP-bug will provided by WordPress in next Version. I´ll send a bug report and the request tho change..